# Select radio button on clicking parent div and get its value in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want a **DIV** behaving like radio button and fetching its value in angularJS. My div looks like :

```
<div ng-repeat="address in multipleaddress" class="tileHover widget Text span4">
     <div class="radios" for="optionsRadios1{{address.id}}" id="{{address.id}}" ng-model="radiosship.shiphere">
        <h3 class="widget-title widget-title" id="shipaddr{{address.id}}">Address #{{$index + 1}}</h3>
        <span style="font-size:16px">{{address.firstname}} {{address.lastname}}</span>
        <p>{{address.shipping_address}}<br/>{{address.shipping_city}}, 
        <span ngif="{{address.country}} == 'CA'">{{address.shipping_province}}</span>
        <span ngif="{{address.country}} == 'US'">{{address.shipping_state}}</span>
        <span ngif="{{address.shipping_country}} != 'US' && {{address.shipping_country}} != 'CA'">{{address.otherregion}}</span> - {{address.pincode}},<br/> {{address.country}}</p>
       <input type="radio" name="shiphere" id="optionsRadios1{{address.id}}" ng-model="radiosship.shiphere" value="{{address.id}}"/>
   </div>
```

when I click on **radios** div, the radio button in that div should get selected and I want its value in **$scope.radiosship.shiphere** in angular.
Any help?

Comment: Did you try adding a onclick method to `radios` div and assign a function in your controller scope. And then update the scope vars accordingly? As in `onClick="radioClick"` and in your controller, `$scope.radioClick` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue here is that a DIV element can not use ng-model directive --assuming that you do not use a custom directive for that--.

so replace `<div class="radios" for="optionsRadios1{{address.id}}" id="{{address.id}}" ng-model="radiosship.shiphere">`
 with 
`<div class="radios" for="optionsRadios1{{address.id}}" id="{{address.id}}" ng-click="radiosship.shiphere = address.id; doSomething(address)">`

also to bind the model value to the controller $scope rather than the components', you can initialize the `radiosship` variable in controller like so:

```
$scope.radiosship = {};
```

here is a working example

```js
   angular.module('App', [])
   .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.radiosship = {};
     $scope.multipleaddress = [
     {id: 1, firstname: 'John'},
     {id: 2, firstname: 'John'},
     {id: 3, firstname: 'John'},
     ];
   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
  <title>Radio</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <pre>{{radiosship | json}}</pre>
  <div ng-repeat="address in multipleaddress" class="tileHover widget Text span4">
     <div class="radios" for="optionsRadios1{{address.id}}" id="{{address.id}}" ng-click="radiosship.shiphere = address.id; fetchData(address)">
        <h3 class="widget-title widget-title" id="shipaddr{{address.id}}">Address #{{$index + 1}}</h3>
        <span style="font-size:16px">{{address.firstname}} {{address.lastname}}</span>
        <p>{{address.shipping_address}}<br/>{{address.shipping_city}}, 
        <span ng-if="address.country == 'CA'">{{address.shipping_province}}</span>
        <span ng-if="address.country == 'US'">{{address.shipping_state}}</span>
        <span ng-if="address.shipping_country != 'US' && address.shipping_country != 'CA'">{{address.otherregion}}</span> - {{address.pincode}},<br/> {{address.country}}</p>
       <input type="radio" name="shiphere" id="optionsRadios1{{address.id}}" ng-model="radiosship.shiphere" value="{{address.id}}"/>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```